# How to display multiple row values after selecting multiple rows?

Tags: spring-mvc, checkbox, jqgrid, multiple-select

I have a jqgrid. when I click on search button,it gives me 2 rows.and if I select 2 rows and click on display, only one row values are being displayed. How to display multiple row values after selecting multiple rows ?

Comment: You wrote "click on display". What is it for the button? What do it? You can use `getGridParm` method with `"selarrrow"` to get the array of ids of selected rows. You can use `getRowData` method for example to get the data of every row by the id. In the way you can get all required information and you need just display the information in the way which you need.

Comment: getDataIds worked for me. Thank You.

Comment: You are welcome! `getDataIDs` returns ids of *all* displayed rows, but you wrote about "selecting multiple rows". Only if you select all rows then `getDataIDs` and `getGridParm("selarrrow")` returns the same results.

Comment: but it is working for me, if I am selecting only one among many,its not returning all...returning just one.

Comment: I suppose that you just use wrong terminology. The row will be selected when the user clicks on one row. If you use `multiselect: true` then you can select multiple rows and there are checkbox which allows to select all rows with one click. If you write about "selecting multiple rows" one understands you that you do this. I suppose that you means absolute another thing. I suppose that you *filtered* (not selected) the grid and displayed subset of rows based on your custom criteria. `getDataIDs` get the array with all (currently filtered) rows from the current page.

Comment: Yes. I wanted to get the IDs of the rows which have been selected and not all the rows... So. didnot use multiselect... getDataIds is working for me with returning Ids of  as many number of rows I have selected...Sorry if I mislead you...